# How to Disable the Home Button in android 4+

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
@Override
protected void onUserLeaveHint()
{
    //Log.d("onUserLeaveHint","Home button pressed");
   Toast.makeText(this,"KEYCODE_HOME", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   // super.onUserLeaveHint();
}
```

Here I can able to detect the Home Key but not able to restrict and IDK how to do that.

A lot of appreciation for the answered person.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> How to Disable the Home Button in android 4+

AFAIK, This is technically not possible for any third party application running in the system except Launcher application.

However, if you are working on an application which is Launcher, you can override the default behavior of Home button.

So, my suggestion would be to rethink about your reason behind disabling Home button and find an alternative way to achieve that.

Comment: Thanks, Will look for it.